# How to access print method of class A in main method? Difference between objects a and b created in main method?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, abstract

How to access print method of class A in main method? Difference between objects a and b created in main method?

```
  abstract class A {
        void print() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        void print() {
        System.out.println("B");
        }
    }



    public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            B b = new B();
            A a = new B();
            b.print();
            a.print();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, `overriden print()` in `class B` will be invoked.

**Case 1:**  `B b = new B();`

this case is straightforward. you create B object with B reference.

**Case2:**   `A a = new B();`

Here, you are creating `B object` with `A reference`. this is called polymorphicaly creating an object or `coding to an interface`. as you have **overridden** `print()` in `class B`, during **run-time** overloaded method of `class B` will be invoked.

**Other option:**

create a method in class B which would invoke print method of class A using super keyword.

```
   class B extends A {
        public void someOtherMethod(){
            super.print();
         }
    }
   from main:
      B  b = new B();
      b.someOthermethod();
```

Comment: I want to decide from main method, which print method will be called not from any predefined methods.

Comment: @Mani as your current code stands, in both the cases B's print will be invoked.

Comment: please explain the difference between two instances a and b. Any extra benefits of using 
            B b = new B();
            or
            A a = new B();

Comment: i believe i have explained it in my answer, however, the first case is straight forward. you are creating an object of class B with reference variable of type B. in the second case you are creating an object of sub class with the super class reference. the benifit of coding this way is that in future say you have  another sub class of A and now instead of creating a new reference variable you can simply make this reference point to the newly created sub-class object.the best and straight forward API examples are Collection class's like List l1 = new ArrayList(); l1 = new LinekedList();

Answer (score 0):

> How to access print method of class A in main method?

You can't, as you don't have an instance of `A`, only of `B`, which has overridden the method.

> Difference between objects a and b created in main method?

They are different instances of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Either initialize a to new A(), not new B(),

or

Add a method to B, called, say, printA()

void printA() {
  super.print();
}